# Issue with Sharedpreferences in kitkat version in android

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-4.2-jelly-bean, android-4.4-kitkat

Hi in my application I am accepting pass code from user and storing it in shared preferences. And, I have provided pass code on/off functionality. If user checked on , app will ask user to enter pass code at the time of launch every time and will be off on checked of Off button.

Everything is working fine on android's ICS, Jellybean version and below. But it never works on Kitkat. Unfortunately, I don't have a Kitkat device to debug my app.
Below is the my code I am using for shared preferences:-

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
//sharedPreferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("ServerData",         Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   sharedPreferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getActivity());
   Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
   editor.putString("Passcode", Globals.str_Passcode);
   editor.commit();
```

Does kitkat has any issues related to shared preferences. 
Please tell me how to resolve this? Or is there any other way to access pass code functionality i same way so it will be accessible in all versions.

Comment: Please explain what "it never works" means.

Comment: it means if I set passcode on, it should ask me for passcode on app launch. but it never happens in kitkat, instead of asking passcode it starts app directly.

Comment: The code that you have listed here is not everything that is related to your problem. For example, to do what you describe, you need to read a value from `SharedPreferences`, and here you only write a value. I would suggest that you set up an Android 4.4 x86 emulator image to be able to debug your app further.

Comment: if you are on emulator, are you sure the delete data on exit app is not enabled?

Comment: @Sean87 : Hi, I tried it on emulator of kitkat version, it is working perfectly, but it is not working on my clients MotoG or Samsung S4.

Comment: check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24760126/2591002) once.

Comment: hey @user3702484 I checked your code on kitkat(motoE) .. its working on ma side..

Answer (score 0):

**Try this way,hope this will help you to solve your problem.**

```
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences(getString(R.string.app_name), MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("Passcode", Globals.str_Passcode);
editor.commit();

sharedPreferences.getBoolean("Passcode",false);
```

Comment: :-  Hi, I tried it on emulator of kitkat version, it is working perfectly, but it is not working on my clients MotoG or Samsung S4.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. It was this missing from MainActivity,

```
prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.prefs, false);
```